# is it possible to run a windows form application with the console application?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to run a windows form application with the console application?

And if so, how would i use the Main() void?

And how could i pass strings over from the windows form to the console?

Comment: What do you mean by "with the" console application? Do you mean you want two processes, with one (a console application) starting another (the Windows form application)?

Comment: Uhm, like the same program. You know how you can get windows form and then the other one? Like an empty project how it starts out as nothing but a cmd thing. Yeah

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean, I'm afraid. A project is *either* a Windows Forms app *or* a console app (or neither). When you double click it from Explorer, it's either going to start up a console or it's not, and when you run it *from* a console, it will either detach itself from that console immediately or not. You can create and display forms from within a console app if you need to, but that's a different matter. If you could clarify what you're really trying to achieve, that would help a lot.

Comment: I think he's trying to rephrase http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426007/forms-and-console/9426064. By the way, interesting micro-celebrity post Jon.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should be possible. Just create a form and put controls in it? Or am I wrong ?

Comment: Alright , sorry. Ok Well What im trying to achieve is i currently have a console form.. Im thinking about adding a gui which is the windows form thing on Visual Studio, so i would add that and i would like the program to start there rather than the console, then theres a username and password box that users would enter their username and password for a website which will pass data from the Windows form to the console app. Then when they click the button on the windows form it would start the console and do its usual business except with the strings that the user inputed. Thanks

Comment: Like Jon said, an application is run as either a Windows Forms app or a Console app. Mixing both isn't recommended unless you absolutely need to. Why can't you just run the entire application as a Windows Form? You could use a RichTextBox to output some text (myRichTextBox.AppendText()). Works just like Console.WriteLine();

Comment: Oh Ok Jason, is there a difference to the code format or is it the same, could i copy n paste?

Comment: So, if you decide to run your application entirely as a Windows Form app, forget all the weird code in your other post. Simply add a RichTextBox control (you can google this more) to your Windows Form, and somewhere in your code file, write "richTextBox1.AppendText("hi");" You may want to get a book on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are saying is that you want to have a console application that can simply open a form. You can do this.

Create your console application as per normal but then add your form to your project (or a reference to a project that contains the form). Then you just want something like this.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm going to open a form now!");
            var form = new Form1();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to add information to your form, you could add properties to the form or a add a custom constructor which takes string information you want sent to the form.

Answer (score 1):

First Create the windows Application like normally you do.

Create a new Console Application

In solution Explorer, goto References->Add Reference->Click Browse Tab->Select Project Path to Debug->Select the Application

Also add a Reference to System.Windows.Form;

In the code

Include the namespace of the Application
using NewForm;// Example

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestForm t = new TestForm(); //Class of WindowsFormApplication NewForm 
        t.ShowDialog();

    }
}
}
```